# What does the error "The element cannot contain white space. Content model is empty." mean?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I'm putting together an xml schema for a simple xml (see bellow for both xml and schema). But I keep getting the following error with regards to the section node: "The element cannot contain white space. Content model is empty." . Browsing the net I could not find any concise explanation as to what it means so I can fix it. Can anyone help?

Edit: thanks for all for offering help with the schema. I think it would help to have a concise description of what content model is and why it is empty here.

XML:

```
<config>
   <section name="facets">
      <facet type="format" label="Format" max="4"/>
      <facet type="language" max="4"/>
      <facet type="pubdate" max="6" submax="8"/> 
      <facet type="ice_topic" label="Fiction: Topic"/>
   </section>
</config>
```

Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <xs:element name="config">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="section" type="sectionBase"/>
         </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
   <xs:complexType name="sectionBase">
      <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:ID"/>
   </xs:complexType>


   <xs:complexType name="sectionFacets" >
      <xs:complexContent>
         <xs:extension base="sectionBase">
            <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element name="facet" type="sectionFacetsBaseFacet"/>
            </xs:sequence>
         </xs:extension>
      </xs:complexContent>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="sectionFacetsBaseFacet">
      <xs:attribute name="label" type="xs:ID"/>
      <xs:attribute name="max" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="sectionFacetsFormat">
      <xs:complexContent>
         <xs:extension base="sectionFacetsBaseFacet"/>
      </xs:complexContent>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name="sectionFacetsPubdate">
      <xs:complexContent>
         <xs:extension base="sectionFacetsBaseFacet">
            <xs:attribute name="submax" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
         </xs:extension>
      </xs:complexContent>

   </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The label attribute of facet is set to xs:ID and this doesn't allow spaces. You might want to use xs:string instead.

Comment: Alex, I accept your answer because it's correct. I still would like to understand what the content model part means. Any idea?

Comment: Reading material about Content models: http://www.stylusstudio.com/w3c/schema0/groups.htm

Answer (score 1):

There are several problem in our schema as others have already mentioned. Try something like this:

**The extensible schema:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <!-- never used; just to be extended -->
    <xs:complexType name="sectionBaseType" abstract="true">
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:ID"/>
    </xs:complexType>

    <!-- extension of the sectionBaseType -->
    <xs:complexType name="sectionSpecialized">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="sectionBaseType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="facet" type="leftToTheReaderType"
                        maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <!-- config may contain a single section or one of its extensions -->
    <xs:complexType name="configType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="section" type="sectionBaseType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <!-- a single root node called "config" -->
    <xs:element name="config" type="configType"/>
</xs:schema>
```

**How to use the schema:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <!-- note the xsi:type to specify the actual type of the section!! -->
    <section name="facets"
        xsi:type="sectionSpecialized">
        <facet .../>
        <facet .../>
        <facet .../> 
        <facet .../>
    </section>
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks janko. Ideally I would avoid setting the type in the xml, as the point of the schema is to validate an xml/give structure it. I don't want to have a two-way dependency between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Your `section` element is defined as type sectionBase, and the `sectionBase` type definition only defines a single attribute. There's no reference anywhere in the schema to the `sectionFacets` type, which is probably what you need.

Try changing the type of the `section` element to `sectionFacets`

Comment: ok - that would work, but I prepared the base type sectionBase to allow multiple section type, of which there is now only one - sectionFacets. What suggest would not allow it.

Comment: Sounds like you need a substitution group