# XmlSchemaValidationException the element cannot contain whitespace

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

When I try to validate the XML scheme I get the following exception:

`System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationException: 'The element cannot contain white space. Content model is empty.'`

I am reading about the same errors but I can't seem to find the solution in these posts.

- [Error validating the XML content: The element cannot contain white space. Content model is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914431/error-validating-the-xml-content-the-element-cannot-contain-white-space-conten)
- [What does the error "The element cannot contain white space. Content model is empty." mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399667/what-does-the-error-the-element-cannot-contain-white-space-content-model-is-em)

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and why?

#### XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="urn://Test.Deploy" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="urn://Test.Deploy" xmlns:mstns="urn://Test.Deploy" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:complexType name="configuration">
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="description" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="deployDir" type="xs:anyURI" use="optional"  default="xs:"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="service">
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="order" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
    <xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="services">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="service" type="service" minOccurs="0" nillable="true" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="environment" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="version" use="required" />
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="configuration" type="configuration"/>

  <xs:element name="services" type="services" />

</xs:schema>
```

#### XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<configuration xmlns="urn://Test.Deploy" id="Test deploy" description="Test deploy server" deployDir="../Deploy">
  <services environment="Development" version="0.1796.0">
    <service name="Foo" order="0" />
    <service name="Bar" />
  </services>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your XSD to this:

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="urn://Test.Deploy" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="urn://Test.Deploy" xmlns:mstns="urn://Test.Deploy" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:complexType name="configuration">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="services" minOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="description" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="deployDir" type="xs:anyURI" use="optional"  default="xs:"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="service">
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="order" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
    <xs:attribute name="version" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="services">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="service" type="service" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="environment" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="version" use="required" />
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="configuration" type="configuration"/>
  <xs:element name="services" type="services" />
</xs:schema>
```

You missed a reference to `services` in `configuration` and a `maxOccurs="unbounded"` in `services`.